# What can a mod do about a comment posted as an answer?

Tags: discussion, review

In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/180029/19) revision of the *Guidelines for reviewing low-quality posts*, we can read under the sub section *Comments posted as an answer*

> If the answer would actually be a constructive comment, consider flagging it for moderator attention.

What would a mod do that a non-mod can't do? Can they transform an answer into a comment?

Comment: Yes, mods can convert answers to comments, or delete them outright if they wouldn't even add value as a comment.